# KendoUI grid never fires destroy method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

My kendoUI never fires destroy method ?  What am I doing wrong. The grid show data properly but fails to delete the record.

```
$("#registration-grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "json",
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("List", "Participant"))",
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "json"                                  
                            },
                            destroy: {
                                url: "http://localhost:53669/api/participant/",
                                type: "DELETE",
                                dataType: "json"                                   
                            }
                        },
                        schema: { data: "Data", total: "Total", model: { id: "Id" } },
                        batch: false,                          
                    },
                    pageable: { ... },
                    editable: { mode: "inline" },                      
                    columns: [
                        {  field: "Id", title: "Id",  width:50,filterable: false },
                     { command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
                    ]                      

                });
```

Web api controller participant: tested on fiddler /api/participant/delete/2 works

```
    [HttpDelete]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        var participant = _participantService.Get(p => p.Id == id);
        if (participant == null)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        try
        {
            _participantService.Delete(participant);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

    }
```

KendoGrid show error when click on Delete 405 Method Not Allowed,  The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE'

Comment: Try changing the verb to HttpPost on controller and set type: "POST" in html. An example here http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing

Comment: The best and low cost solution is: change `httpdelete verb` to `httppost` verb

Answer (score 1):

This is not problem with Kendo, just with HttpDelete.

Problem is with WebDAV module and answears from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413455/why-does-http-delete-verb-return-405-error-method-not-allowed-for-my-restful-w) work for me very well. In short just change your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" /> 
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```